# Image Button Event Not Working

Tags: java, android

I had create a simple app where there is a image button.

I want a toast to be worked after clicking the image button.

My problem is that, I can see that image button but while clicking on that imagebutton nothing happens. I can't find any issues with that code. 
Here is my code.

Here is my xml File

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ContentMain.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContentMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton imgButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        imgButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You download is resumed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: I also cannot find any errors in your code. I'd suggest you try to write `ContentMain.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in the `Toast.makeText` line to see whether it makes any difference. You are not getting any errors, right? Also, I'd try to `log` in the `onClick` listener to see if it even enters that function: `Log.i("YOOOO", "I'm here");`

Comment: put some break points and debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should Debug yourself first**

You can use this way

add this in your Xml

```
 <ImageButton
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="myClick"
    />
```

Then

in Java class

```
public void myClick(View v)
{
 Toast.makeText(ContentMain.this,"You download is resumed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Clean-Rebuild-Run**

Comment: I had uploaded the work file. Can anybody resolve my issue plz.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Ax58vO7SvZcm5va0xHeXdNWm8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I had alot of troubles with functions that uses context in OnClicklisteners try create a method for the toast and then call it from the clicklistener like this:

Private void callToast(){

Insert your function toast here
}

ImgButton.setOnClicklistener(new OnClicklistener){

callToast()
{

Comment: In-class methods vs anonymous classes, it shouldn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

It works (I pasted your code to my project), maybe try clear your project.

Comment: Yes. The code has no errors, everything works perfectly.

Comment: If you have enough rep, you could flag the question as unable to reproduce, but this is a very low quality answer on its own

Comment: I had uploaded the package. Please resolve it  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Ax58vO7SvZcm5va0xHeXdNWm8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Add to xml:

```
<ImageButton
android:clickable="true" />
```

activity:

```
implements View.OnClickListener

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageButton imgButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You download is resumed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the onClick from the XML if you are going to override it in the Java code anyways