# Image Button Click Event is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I had create a small for testing and studying purpose. It consist of an image button and the action is to show a toast while pressing the image button.

I had changed everything but toast message is not showing. There is no single error or warning in the code.

Last day, I posted the code here and didn't get an answer.

So this time I uploaded the Source code. Hope somebody can solve this simple solution.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Ax58vO7SvZcGRwNFlyYzhqZFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you can put break point in your "onClick" function in "ContentMain" class and check that dose it fire after clicking or not? and if it has fire check to see to see what is the value of "v.getId()".

Comment: Where did you post your code? Can you share that again?

Comment: I found you post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485477/image-button-event-not-working, and there are several answers, and you have not respond to them if their answers works or not.

Comment: I had tested every answers but nothing works. All code works without any errors but no result. Kindly help me. I am a beginner.. Plz..

Comment: Have you tried to put the action of the button in the onResume() method? Just a guess, but that is where I usually put them, as that is called even when you change orientation.

Comment: it didnt worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove this code from content and place it in MainActivity.java

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You download is resumed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Rememeber

If you set any onClick event in a layout file (xml), you have to create the method in the parent activity that will use that layout.

this is complete wroking code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="switchmode.lteonly.lteonlyswitch.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You download is resumed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Contentmain.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    ImageButton imgButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
  //  imgButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome.  Thanx it worked...  You solved the answer by explaining the reason. Thanx thanx thanx....